# Why is my relative layout filling the screen rather than wrapping content when I add an image?

Tags: android, button, imageview, margin, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout, we'll call this the 'slider', that I want to overlay on another RelativeLayout (by switching visibility="gone" and "visible") when "Add People" is clicked, but the overlay should only take up as much width of the screen as needed.  This layout will then be removed when "Cancel" is clicked. Everything is working fine so far.

[image: correct_closed]
[image: correct_open]

```
RelativeLayout slider;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_people);
    RelativeLayout add = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_wrapper);
    RelativeLayout cancel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.cancel_wrapper);
    slider = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_people_slider);

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            slider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

The issue arises when I try to add another image to the slider.  I am adding this just above the @id/cancel_wrapper RelativeLayout in the XML (full XML at bottom).

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transparent_add"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_active_256"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

[image: bad]

For some reason, this is making the width of the slider the full width of the screen.

What's even more bizarre is if I add `android:layout_marginRight="50dp"` to this ImageView to move it left a little it starts making the slider smaller from the left.  I would like this "transparent_add" image to be lined up with the old "add" image.

[image: bad with margin]

My 2 issues, then, are that when I add the "transparent_add" image it changes the width of the slider for an unknown reason, and also when I add marginRight on the image it makes the width of the slider smaller from the left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn_people"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/label_people"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/people_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_people"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/label_people_info"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/blue" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plus_sign"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_256" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_people"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="@string/label_add_people"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="11dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/people_info" />

<!-- switch between visible/gone -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_people_slider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_add_new_contact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="@string/label_add_new_contact"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_add_from_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_add_new_contact"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/label_add_from_phone"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_add_from_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_add_from_phone"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/label_add_from_facebook"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_add_from_linkedin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_add_from_facebook"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/label_add_from_linkedin"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <!-- insert image here -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cancel_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_cancel"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_256"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/label_cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: This is happening both in Eclipse and on my Android device.

EDIT: I have tried placing the image above the "Add a new contact" text and then placing the text below that, but the same thing happens

Comment: Would it be any easier to use a ViewFlipper to do this?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of your layout for us to have an idea how it looks like?

Comment: @Joel I need to overlay one view on the other, it looks like a ViewFlipper chooses between two views and only displays one at a time.